# Call Child class method from Parent class method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, methods

Consider the following case

```
class A
{
    X()
    {
        //some code
        Y();
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    Y(){ //some code }
}
```

If I create an object of the class `B`, and i try to use function `X` as it is extended from `A`, is it possible that the function `X` can access the function `Y` of the calling object of class `B`.

Comment: Obvious question: why do you want to do that? It looks to me like a XY problem

Comment: why would you want to do that? Its considered an anti-pattern to get super class to call a method on child class. I think you might wanna look into abstract classes and its method declaration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could but this must be met

1. A class is abstract
2. Y method is abstract too

---

Example:

```
abstract class A {
    void X() {
        Y();
    }

    abstract void Y();
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    void Y() {
        System.out.println("Hello from B class");
    }
}
```

in that form every time class A calls Y, it will actually invoke an implememted method of the abstract method Y

Comment: I took the liberty to link your answer in mine as yours already explain pretty well that solution. Don't hesite to mention it if it is a problem ;)

Comment: Visual Studio 2022:  `A` declaraion of `Y()` cannot be `private`, so `abstract protected void Y()` was needed.  Then, in `B`:  remove `@Override`, and instead `override protected void Y()`.

Answer (score 0):

only if `A` have a method with the same signature (or a super class has one), otherwise it can't find/use a method that is not defined in his context.

This could be done

- with an implementation of the method in `A`
- by using an abstract method in `A`(see [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44430953/4391450)).

The first solution is not always the best, as you could have a method that do nothing in `A` like :

```
class A{
    void Y(){}
}
```

Note : if you have `Y()` in both class, the polymorphism assure you that an instance of `B` will use his own implementation.

The second solution can be problematic if you want to be able to create instance of `A` as it will be abstract.